# OpenGL- Combining two Shader Gaussian Blur and Contrast

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm trying to combine two shader to create smooth color by new version OpenGL in Android (Updated at Dec 2014) but not work. Here are the Shader:

**In Gaussian Blur**

Vertex Shader:

```
public static final String VERTEX_SHADER =
        "attribute vec4 position;\n" +
                "attribute vec4 inputTextureCoordinate;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "const int GAUSSIAN_SAMPLES = 9;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "uniform float texelWidthOffset;\n" +
                "uniform float texelHeightOffset;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "varying vec2 textureCoordinate;\n" +
                "varying vec2 blurCoordinates[GAUSSIAN_SAMPLES];\n" +
                "\n" +
                "void main()\n" +
                "{\n" +
                "   gl_Position = position;\n" +
                "   textureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate.xy;\n" +
                "   \n" +
                "   // Calculate the positions for the blur\n" +
                "   int multiplier = 0;\n" +
                "   vec2 blurStep;\n" +
                "   vec2 singleStepOffset = vec2(texelHeightOffset, texelWidthOffset);\n" +
                "    \n" +
                "   for (int i = 0; i < GAUSSIAN_SAMPLES; i++)\n" +
                "   {\n" +
                "       multiplier = (i - ((GAUSSIAN_SAMPLES - 1) / 2));\n" +
                "       // Blur in x (horizontal)\n" +
                "       blurStep = float(multiplier) * singleStepOffset;\n" +
                "       blurCoordinates[i] = inputTextureCoordinate.xy + blurStep;\n" +
                "   }\n" +
                "}\n";
```

Fragment Shader:

```
public static final String FRAGMENT_SHADER =
        "uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "const lowp int GAUSSIAN_SAMPLES = 9;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;\n" +
                "varying highp vec2 blurCoordinates[GAUSSIAN_SAMPLES];\n" +
                "\n" +
                "void main()\n" +
                "{\n" +
                "   lowp vec3 sum = vec3(0.0);\n" +
                "   lowp vec4 fragColor=texture2D(inputImageTexture,textureCoordinate);\n" +
                "   \n" +
                "    sum += texture2D(inputImageTexture, blurCoordinates[0]).rgb * 0.05;\n" +
                "    sum += texture2D(inputImageTexture, blurCoordinates[1]).rgb * 0.09;\n" +
                "    sum += texture2D(inputImageTexture, blurCoordinates[2]).rgb * 0.12;\n" +
                "    sum += texture2D(inputImageTexture, blurCoordinates[3]).rgb * 0.15;\n" +
                "    sum += texture2D(inputImageTexture, blurCoordinates[4]).rgb * 0.18;\n" +
                "    sum += texture2D(inputImageTexture, blurCoordinates[5]).rgb * 0.15;\n" +
                "    sum += texture2D(inputImageTexture, blurCoordinates[6]).rgb * 0.12;\n" +
                "    sum += texture2D(inputImageTexture, blurCoordinates[7]).rgb * 0.09;\n" +
                "    sum += texture2D(inputImageTexture, blurCoordinates[8]).rgb * 0.05;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "   gl_FragColor = vec4(sum,fragColor.a);\n" +
                "}";
```

**In Contrast**:

NO_Vertext_Shader

and Fragment shader:

```
public static final String CONTRAST_FRAGMENT_SHADER = ""
        + "varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;\n"
        + " \n"
        + " uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;\n"
        + " uniform lowp float contrast;\n"
        + " \n"
        + " void main()\n"
        + " {\n"
        + "     lowp vec4 textureColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);\n"
        + "     \n"
        + "     gl_FragColor = vec4(((textureColor.rgb - vec3(0.5)) * contrast + vec3(0.5)), textureColor.w);\n"
        + " }";
```

How can I do that ???, I can combine some shader but it is so difficult in this case

Sorry my english not good.

Update:

How can I merge if with two Sharpen shader (Merger Sharpen shader with Gaussian Blur shader):

***Two Sharpen Shader***

**Vertex Shader:**

```
public static final String SHARPEN_VERTEX_SHADER = "" +
        "attribute vec4 position;\n" +
        "attribute vec4 inputTextureCoordinate;\n" +
        "\n" +
        "uniform float imageWidthFactor; \n" +
        "uniform float imageHeightFactor; \n" +
        "uniform float sharpness;\n" +
        "\n" +
        "varying vec2 textureCoordinate;\n" +
        "varying vec2 leftTextureCoordinate;\n" +
        "varying vec2 rightTextureCoordinate; \n" +
        "varying vec2 topTextureCoordinate;\n" +
        "varying vec2 bottomTextureCoordinate;\n" +
        "\n" +
        "varying float centerMultiplier;\n" +
        "varying float edgeMultiplier;\n" +
        "\n" +
        "void main()\n" +
        "{\n" +
        "    gl_Position = position;\n" +
        "    \n" +
        "    mediump vec2 widthStep = vec2(imageWidthFactor, 0.0);\n" +
        "    mediump vec2 heightStep = vec2(0.0, imageHeightFactor);\n" +
        "    \n" +
        "    textureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate.xy;\n" +
        "    leftTextureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate.xy - widthStep;\n" +
        "    rightTextureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate.xy + widthStep;\n" +
        "    topTextureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate.xy + heightStep;     \n" +
        "    bottomTextureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate.xy - heightStep;\n" +
        "    \n" +
        "    centerMultiplier = 1.0 + 4.0 * sharpness;\n" +
        "    edgeMultiplier = sharpness;\n" +
        "}";
```

**Fragment Shader:**

```
public static final String SHARPEN_FRAGMENT_SHADER = "" +
        "precision highp float;\n" + 
        "\n" + 
        "varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;\n" + 
        "varying highp vec2 leftTextureCoordinate;\n" + 
        "varying highp vec2 rightTextureCoordinate; \n" + 
        "varying highp vec2 topTextureCoordinate;\n" + 
        "varying highp vec2 bottomTextureCoordinate;\n" + 
        "\n" + 
        "varying highp float centerMultiplier;\n" + 
        "varying highp float edgeMultiplier;\n" + 
        "\n" + 
        "uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;\n" + 
        "\n" + 
        "void main()\n" + 
        "{\n" + 
        "    mediump vec3 textureColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate).rgb;\n" + 
        "    mediump vec3 leftTextureColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, leftTextureCoordinate).rgb;\n" + 
        "    mediump vec3 rightTextureColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, rightTextureCoordinate).rgb;\n" + 
        "    mediump vec3 topTextureColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, topTextureCoordinate).rgb;\n" + 
        "    mediump vec3 bottomTextureColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, bottomTextureCoordinate).rgb;\n" + 
        "\n" + 
        "    gl_FragColor = vec4((textureColor * centerMultiplier - (leftTextureColor * edgeMultiplier + rightTextureColor * edgeMultiplier + topTextureColor * edgeMultiplier + bottomTextureColor * edgeMultiplier)), texture2D(inputImageTexture, bottomTextureCoordinate).w);\n" + 
        "}";
```

Comment: Could you tell me why you need to create all those as strings here? Thanks.

Comment: I want to make a smooth color like camera 360 :|. How do you feel that

Answer (score 0):

Why is it difficult in this case? It seems to me that all you need to do is use the contrast on the Gaussian blur output. That means you need to merge the last line (in main) of Gaussian blur fragment shader with the first line in Contrast shader to:

```
lowp vec4 textureColor = vec4(sum,fragColor.a);
```

And add `uniform lowp float contrast;` on the top of the shader. Other then that you keep all from the blur shader above this line and all from the Contrast shader below this line:

```
   uniform lowp float contrast;

   //.. insert Gaussian shader till gl_FragColor..

   lowp vec4 textureColor = vec4(sum,fragColor.a);
   gl_FragColor = vec4(((textureColor.rgb - vec3(0.5)) * contrast + vec3(0.5)), textureColor.w);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it work when i merge Contrast with Gaussian Blur